# LLVM Assertion error when using module pass inside loop pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing several LLVM passes. One of them is a ModulePass that performs some analyzations but does not change anything (no functions, no metadata, no variables,...). It only looks at some metadata nodes and thats it.

MyModuleChecker.cpp:

```
INITIALIZE_PASS_BEGIN(MyModuleChecker, "mmc", "Check module",  false, true)
INITIALIZE_PASS_END(MyModuleChecker, "mmc", "Check module",  false, true)

char MyModuleChecker::ID = 0;

namespace llvm {
  Pass* createMyModuleCheckerPass() {
    return new MyModuleChecker();
  }
}

MyModuleChecker::MyModuleChecker(void) : ModulePass(ID) {
  initializeMyModuleCheckerPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
}

void MyModuleChecker::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
  AU.setPreservesAll();
}

bool MyModuleChecker::runOnModule(Module &M) {
  // ...
  return false; // <-- Under all circumstances
}
```

And then there is a second pass. That pass is a LoopPass and basiclly performs some loop unrolling tasks depending on some criteria. For computing the unroll count the pass needs the results of the `MyModuleChecker` pass. So I put it in the dependencies.

MyLoopUnroll.cpp:

```
INITIALIZE_PASS_BEGIN(MyLoopUnroll, "myloopunroll", "Unroll loops",  false, false)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(LoopInfo)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(ScalarEvolution)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(MyModuleChecker)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(DataLayoutPass)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(AssumptionCacheTracker)
INITIALIZE_PASS_END(MyLoopUnroll, "myloopunroll", "Unroll loops",  false, false)

char MyLoopUnroll::ID = 0;

namespace llvm {
  Pass* createMyLoopUnrollPass() {
    return new MyLoopUnroll();
  }
}

MyLoopUnroll::MyLoopUnroll()
 : LoopPass(ID), MDK(nullptr), LI(nullptr), SE(nullptr), AC(nullptr),
   DL(nullptr) {
  initializeMyLoopUnrollPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
}

void HDLLoopUnroll::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
  AU.addRequired<LoopInfo>();
  AU.addRequired<ScalarEvolution>();
  AU.addRequired<MyModuleChecker>();
  AU.addPreserved<MyModuleChecker>();
  AU.addRequired<DataLayoutPass>();
  AU.addPreserved<DataLayoutPass>();
  AU.addRequired<AssumptionCacheTracker>();
}

bool MyLoopUnroll::runOnLoop(Loop *L, LPPassManager &LPM) {
  LI = &getAnalysis<LoopInfo>();
  SE = &getAnalysis<ScalarEvolution>();
  MDK = &getAnalysis<MyModuleChecker>();    // <-- Seems not to work
  DL = &getAnalysis<DataLayoutPass>().getDataLayout();
  AC = &getAnalysis<AssumptionCacheTracker>().getAssumptionCache(*L->getHeader()->getParent());

  if ((LI == nullptr) || (SE == nullptr) || (DL == nullptr) || (MDK == nullptr) || (AC == nullptr)) {
    return false;
  }

  bool Changed = handleLoop(L, LPM);
  return Changed;
}
```

The loop unrolling itself was not implemented by myself but instead I am using the already existing functions that LLVM provides and that are also used by the loop unrolling that LLVM provides.

Currently those passes are part of the Scalar-library so I adopted the corresponding files (include /llvm/Transforms/Scalar.h, LinkAllPasses.h, ...) accordingly. So my passes are not linked dynamicly to opt.

Now I want to run the passes using opt (I'm using LLVM 3.6):

```
opt -stats -debug -debug-pass=Structure -mem2reg -loop-rotate -myloopunroll -simplifycfg
```

I now get an assertion error:

```
LoopRotation: rotating Loop at depth 1 containing: %for.cond<header><exiting>,%for.body,%for.inc<latch>
  Inserted PHI:   %i.01 = phi i32 [ 0, %entry ], [ %i.0, %for.cond ]
  LoopRotation: into Loop at depth 1 containing: %for.body<header>,%for.inc<latch><exiting>
opt: ~/llvm-clang/source/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:214: AnalysisType& llvm::Pass::getAnalysisID(llvm::AnalysisID) const [with AnalysisType = MyModuleChecker; llvm::AnalysisID = const void*]: Assertion `ResultPass && "getAnalysis*() called on an analysis that was not " "'required' by pass!"' failed.
// ...
#8 0x1685a99 MyModuleChecker& llvm::Pass::getAnalysisID<MyModuleChecker>(void const*) const ()
#9 0x16857f0 MyModuleChecker& llvm::Pass::getAnalysis<MyModuleChecker>() const ()
#10 0x16853cd MyLoopUnroll::runOnLoop(llvm::Loop*, llvm::LPPassManager&) ()
#11 0xd34aaa llvm::LPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) ()
// ...
```

And I don't know where that error comes and why it occures (any yes, everything compiles without errors and warnings). It looks like the loop rotation pass is executed normally and then pass manager gets stuck in the loop unroll pass when calling the `getAnalysis<MyModuleChecker>;` analysis results.

If I ommit the `-simplifycfg` and do not run the simplifycfg pass after my own loopunrolling pass everything works fine on the sameprogram and there is no assertion error. Afterwards the loop is unrolled.
It also seems as if the error does not occur if the ModuleChecker pass is transformed into a FunctionPass.
Could anyone tell my why this assertion error occures and (perhaps) how to solve that issue?